# Linux system() and signal handler cause a race condition?

Tags: c, linux, unix, gtk, signals

I came across a problem with code like:

```
void sighandler(int signo)
{
    printf("sighandler() called\n");

    pid_t pid;
    pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);
    if(pid >= 0)
    {
        printf("Caught by sighandler(): pid = %d\n", pid);
    }
    else
    {
        perror("sighandler pid failed");
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    int ret = 0;
    pid_t pid;

    signal(SIGCHLD, sighandler);

    ret = system("ls -al");

    if(ret < 0)
    {
        perror("system failed");
        printf("return value is %d\n", ret);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

1. In Linux(Cent OS) environment, `sighandler()` will be triggered after `system()` finishes. But on Mac OS X, `sighandler()` is not called in the same condition.  Is this a known difference between Linux and BSD/UNIX systems?
2. The real problem is that in a GTK(C Language) program, `SIGCHLD` is bind with `sighandler()` in the main routine. But later I discover that a `system()` called in a callback function of child window GTK Button always returns -1. I'm fully sure that `SIGCHLD` is not bind with `SIG_IGN` and it is still bind `sighandler()`. **Is it possible that `waitpid` in `sighandler()` catch the dead child process before `waitpid()` in `system()` which is intended to handle the dead child process?**

Comment: Sigh, it's really hard to google for this, because "system" matches "operating system" and "system call", and these are frequently found on the same page as "SIGCHLD"

Comment: @Barmar You are absolutely right. I spent hours on it even though I can make system() works properly by bind SIGCHLD with SIG_DFL before call it. But it really confuses me a lot since I can't reappear the problem by writing a program myself: every time the dead process is handled by the system() itself and nothing goes wrong at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the POSIX specification of [system](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html) says regarding `SIGCHLD`:

> The system() function shall ignore the SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals, and shall block the SIGCHLD signal, while waiting for the command to terminate.
>
> Blocking SIGCHLD while waiting for the child to terminate prevents the application from catching the signal and obtaining status from system()'s child process before system() can get the status itself.
>
> Note that if the application is catching SIGCHLD signals, it will receive such a signal before a successful system() call returns.

The last point is because when `system()` unblocks `SIGCHLD`, the pending signal is delivered, and it goes to the application's handler.